# Replacing many things using replace() in one line

Tags: java

I wonder if there is a way to use replace() with multiple replacement in one line in java. for example:

```
String precio_gold = "59,99$";
precio_gold = precio_gold.replace(",", ".");
precio_gold = precio_gold.replace("$", "");
```

And also if I there is a way to introduce more posibilites in the first "argument" of replace method, for example receive a price and depending if it has $ or € replace with "" (nothing):

```
precio_gold = precio_gold.replace("$" AND "€", ""); //This is wrong but I put just to see what I want to say.
```

Comment: Use [`replaceAll`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-) instead of `replace`, which takes a [regular expression](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/) as its first argument (instead of a literal string to replace): `precio_gold.replaceAll("\\$|€", "");`

Comment: Better regex : `[$€]` (`$` has no special meaning in a character class so it does not need to be escaped)

Comment: @Jesper : added an answer quite similar to your comment...

Comment: We're talking regex, but you should instead be using a localized `NumberFormat`. See [this SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9892555/parsing-prices-with-currency-symbol-in-java)

Comment: Rather than always replacing "," with ".", I suggest you output the decimal point using a Locale-dependent formatter instead. If you hard-code it to ".", sooner or later some European will complain that your output is wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For your first problem, doing multiple replaces on one line, you could just chain the method.

```
System.out.println(precio_gold.replace(",", ".").replace("$", ""));
```

For your second problem, you could use replaceAll with a regex.

```
System.out.println(precio_gold.replaceAll("\\$|€", ""));
```

Note that `$` is escaped with `\\` since it's a special character in a regular expression.

Comment: Worked for both cases! Thanks to all the replies!

Answer (score 2):

If you're allowed to use Apache Commons then this is what you're looking for:

```
StringUtils.replaceEach(String text, String[] searchList, String[] replacementList)
```

you can find more examples in the documentation [here](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html#replaceEach-java.lang.String-java.lang.String:A-java.lang.String:A-).

Answer (score 1):

This one should work for you

```
precio_gold = precio_gold.replaceAll("[$€]", "");
```

Answer (score 1):

You can always try with

```
precio_gold = precio_gold.replace(",", ".").replaceAll("\\$|€", "");
```

or even

```
precio_gold = "59,99$".replace(",", ".").replaceAll("\\$|€", "");
```

Answer (score 0):

You wanted to know if there are more possiblities in the first argument.
I say, you can use `Ternary operator` in the first argument to pick and choose conditionally what exactly you want to change.

Here's a brief example:

```
    String precio_gold = "FFF#vvty^kk^k#hhh9";
    precio_gold = precio_gold.replace(precio_gold.indexOf("#") ==3 ? "#": "^", "0");
    // precio_gold = precio_gold.replace("$", "");
    System.out.println(precio_gold);
```

This code checks if the `"#"` is at the 3rd index and if only its at 3rd index, it gets replaced with `0`, else the `^` gets replaced with 0.

You can keep adding to the conditions after the `:` in the `ternary` operator.

Nice one lined approach. Hope it helps!